# Custom calendar view on a button click(weekly,monthly and yearly)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i am trying to create the calendar which will give me weekly,monthly and yearly view on a button click.but i am only able to do yearly which is iPhone's default calender.Is there any other method to cutomize it???
here what I have done till now
PS:I am begineer in iOS :)

```
-(void)YearBtn
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
}
```

[image: i want to create like this]

&

[image: like this]

Comment: You need to customize the view. There is no default date picker like this.

Comment: Set buttons with label customly according to your  month view.Prepare iPhone or iMac calendar.It will show you the result.

Comment: using xib??and how to do it's operations ??

Comment: I have made the same design with buttons and labels but don't know what to do ahead? plz help .!!! @user3182143

Comment: I  am on leave for Today and Tomorrow.If you can wait till on Thursday,I will show you the output.

Comment: okay.No worries.

Comment: @user3182143 hello ,is there any demo ??

Comment: wait I will give you

Comment: @user3182143 did you got ??

Comment: Definitely I will help you out.Wait for some time.

Comment: @user3182143 I used native calendar for temp. purpose.

Comment: Tomorrow I will help you for sure

Comment: I il show you output

Comment: anyone know the calendar where I can show the selected date on label??